# Page not found when there are clean extra parameters in URL alias-

Tags: path-aliases

I have a working site which has PathAuto with SubPath setting properly configured. When I try to access the site from localhost in XAMPP, it gives 404 not found at several pages where the clean URL has extra parameters.

For example,  this goes perfect: subdomain.example.com/url-friendly/extra-parameters

This, in local PC: www.example2.com/url-friendly/ goes right
This, in local PC. fails www.example2.com/url-friendly/extra-parameters

Is there some known issue with XAMPP and Drupal url alias?

Comment: "with SubPath setting properly configured" - how do you know? Do you have Linux-based instance of your site somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

I have discovered the problem and the solution. When you change domain, or you add a domain to the list in **Domain Access**, you later have to switch off **SubPath**, save, and later turn on SubPath again. In that way, it refresh "something", and everything works perfectly.

So if you have free parameters passed on the *clean friendly URLs*, you need to make those steps in order to assure that the site will work with the changed or added domains.